# Detecting USB mouse. Qt on Embedded Linux

Tags: c++, qt, embedded-linux, udev, hotplugging

I need to hide the cursor when USB mouse is disconnected from the system, and show it when the mouse is connected. Any ideas how it can be done?

Comment: Do you have X running on this system? If so you can try the methods [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660613/how-do-you-hide-the-mouse-pointer-under-linux-x11#696855).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt itself does not provide such a module. There is a user-made class called [QDeviceWatcher](https://github.com/wang-bin/qdevicewatcher), you could give it a try.

If you are using  QtEmbedded Linux, you have a folder with all USB devices info (vendor id, etc), probably in `/proc/scsi/usb-storage` file. So you probably could use [QFileSystemWatcher](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfilesystemwatcher.html) to handle modification in this folder.

See: [Qt Centre Post](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/21841-Detection-usb-device-connection-disconnection) for more detail.

Comment: `QFileSystemWatcher` on Linux uses `inotify`, but the entries in `/proc/` are not files. They do _look_ like files, in the sense that most entries contain text, but `inotify` doesn't work on them. And this isn't something that realistically can be fixed; some of these entries are continuously changing.

Comment: QDeviceWatcher works well. However, it's a problem to understand that the device you connected is actually a mouse. A usb dongle is seen as an "USB Receiver" (for wired mouse it is "optical mouse"). Any ideas about that?