# Hide cursor when a specific program is running

Tags: python

I'm checking if the game is active and If it is I'm trying to hide the mouse cursor just for comfort reasons since it annoys me. But I can't find any way to do it... Any suggestions? I'm pretty new to Python.

```
import psutil
def isRunning(name):
    for pid in psutil.pids():
        prcs = psutil.Process(pid)
        if name in prcs.name():
            return True

while(isRunning("Brawlhalla")):
    # do stuff here
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using an external program. If you are under Linux, check `unclutter` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/x11/unclutter for example - if you are using ubuntu).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660613/how-do-you-hide-the-mouse-pointer-under-linux-x11) lists other ways to hide the mouse cursor more or less permanently.

By the way this is not strictly speaking a Python question, and using a python script is probably not the proper way to achieve what you want... You'd better launch unclutter or one of its friends from a console and be done with it.

But assuming you really insist on using Python and your `isRunning()` code is correct, one naive way to implement what you want in python could look like this (leaving aside corner cases handling):

```
from time import sleep
import subprocess

(your isRunning code here)

proc = subprocess.Popen(["unclutter", "-root", "-idle", "0"])
while (isRunning("Brawlhalla")):
    sleep(1)
proc.terminate()
```

Comment: Is there another way since I'm running Windows..?